# How to create one fragment at a time using viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I am using two fragments inside viewpager. In the second fragment, I play a video from url using exoplayer. My problem is that when the activity is launch, the video is loaded automatically because all fragments are automatically created by viewpager. How to create one frament at a time so that the second fragment can play the video only if it is visible to the user (by swipping or tapping the tab).

The viewpager adapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    Bundle bundle;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Bundle bundle) {
        super(manager);
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d("getItem", position + "");
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                IngredientListFragment ingredientListFragment = new IngredientListFragment();
                ingredientListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return ingredientListFragment;
            case 1:
                StepsListFragment stepsListFragment = new StepsListFragment();
                stepsListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return stepsListFragment;
            default:
                IngredientListFragment ing = new IngredientListFragment();
                ing.setArguments(bundle);
                return ing;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Ingredients";
            case 1:
                return "Steps";
            default:
                return "Ingredients";
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the activity

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

                TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

                ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), bundle);

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to create fragment one at a time:
use this code in second fragment to run exoplayer when user open that fragment:

```
    private boolean _hasLoadedOnce = false; // your boolean field

        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible_) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(true);

            if (this.isVisible()) {
                if (isFragmentVisible_ && !_hasLoadedOnce) {

                    // move exoplayer code here so this code run only when user select this fragment

                   _hasLoadedOnce = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

One more thing, you have to put this line after creating viewpager:
in your case after

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @divyesh-patel . Your solution work well.